# Data type assignment TS+Vue3

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

In my components, i want to use `<script setup lang="ts">` . But I ran into a type problem.
Example of a normal component `<script lang="ts">`:

```
props: {
    modelValue: {
      type: [Boolean, String, Number, Array as () => Array<string | number>],
      required: true,
    },
    value: {
      type: [Boolean, String, Number, Array as () => Array<string>],
      default: "",
    },
    label: {
      type: [String, Number],
      default: "",
    },
}
```

Component `<script setup lang="ts">`. How to correctly set such types in the interface ?

```
interface Props {
  modelValue: [Boolean, String, Number, Array as () => Array<string | number>]
  value: [Boolean, String, Number, Array as () => Array<string>]
  label: [String, Number]
}
const props = defineProps<Props>()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To combine types in TypeScript, use [union types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types). For instance, this constructor array:

```js
[Boolean, String, Number, Array as () => Array<string | number>]
```

...becomes this in type in TypeScript:

```js
boolean | string | number | (string | number)[]
```

So, the equivalent TypeScript interface of your original code would be:

```js
interface Props {
  modelValue: boolean | string | number | (string | number)[]
  value: boolean | string | number | string[]
  label: string | number
}
const props = defineProps<Props>()
```

To set default values for the props, use [`withDefaults()`](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#default-props-values-when-using-type-declaration):

```js
const props = withDefaults(defineProps<Props>(), {
  value: '',
  label: '',
})
```

...or use [object destructuring with default values](https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/reactivity-transform.html#reactive-props-destructure):

```js
const {
  modelValue = '',
  value = '',
  label = '',
} = defineProps<Props>()
```